# Eagle Schematic - adding net does not reflect changes in PCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I have unfinished schematic with PCB. When I add net in schematic, the route is not visible in PCB and I cannot connect pins. Why? I am adding two screenshots for better understanding of problem, first screenshot is a schematic and a second one is pcb of same schematic!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you create a new netlist, and import that netlist into the PCB? (I haven't used Eagle, but that is the required procedure in programs I have used - terminology may vary slightly...)

Comment: @PeterBennett Eagle has back-annotation. No ex/import of netlists is necessary.

Comment: @us2012 The OP said he changed the schematic, but the change didn't appear on the PCB - that's "front annotation", usually involving updated netlists, not back-annotation, which sends PCB changes back to the schematic.

Comment: I have added links to screenshot. I could not add screenshots directly because of website reported error to me.

Comment: @MarkoFrelih: What happens if you add a new part to the schematic? Is this correctly reflected on the board?

Comment: @PeterBennett: Eagle supports full forward/backward annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the schematic and board are in sync?  Are you adding a net between pins on the schematic?

Beyond that, it is difficult to come up with a meaningful answer with such little information.

### Added:

You now say you are not adding a net between pins on the schematic, and no, I really can't see much of anything from those screenshots.  Without actually connecting pins, Eagle doesn't know the connection exists.  As a result, it doesn't show any airwire for the connection in the board, since there is in fact no connection.

Go to the schematic and use the NET command to draw a connection between two pins you want connected.  That should cause a airwire to show up in the board.  Alternatively, you can draw a short stub using NET from each pin, then give both stubs the same name.  One way or another, you have to explain to Eagle that the two pins are connected.  Once you do that, the corresponding airwire will appear in the board.

Comment: I think sch and pcb are in sync, i.e., how could I check this? I am NOT adding net between pins as you can see from screenshots.

Comment: I have managed to connect all the pins on schematics, and they show in PCB. I also moved ZCEN/ signal to other connector pin and I still do not get route in pcb. I've added screenshots:[Schematic](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/818/cyo.png/) and [PCB](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/221/9f6l.png/).

Comment: @MarkoFrelih: Why did you accept this answer, even though it did not solve your problem?

Comment: It was a guideline ...

Answer (score 0):

I have reconnected ZCEN signal from IC to connector and now the problem has been solved! ZCEN signal from IC is now connected to connector in PCB!